# Binary deserializing generic object in C#

Tags: c#-4.0, generics, casting, deserialization, binary-deserialization

I have a generic class which can be serialized:

```
MyOwnGenericClass<T>
```

So I want to deserialize it and if `T` is a `String` instance handle it, in another case I want to throw an exception.

How to know type of generic contains in `MyOwnGenericClass<T>` while deserializing?
To what class I have to cast following code?

```
new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(fileStrieam);
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.aspx - search for "generic", one of those methods/properties will in all likelihood be what you're looking for.

Comment: "So I want to deserialize it and if T is a String instance handle it, in another case I want to throw an exception." Isn't that a little bit in conflict of you class being generic?

Comment: @bas oh, yeah :) I reread my question and realize that is a little bit in conflict... It's not what I really need, but if I know how to do that I'll can do what I really need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's really easy. Just use `object` like so:

```
object obj = new BinaryFormatter().Deserialize(fileStrieam);
```

and then do what you said you would do:

```
if (!(obj is MyOwnGenericClass<string>))
    throw new Exception("It was something other than MyOwnGenericClass<string>");
else {
    MyOwnGenericClass<string> asMyOwn_OfString = obj as MyOwnGenericClass<string>;

    // do specific stuff with it
    asMyOwn.SpecificStuff();
}
```

So you're not checking if `T` is a `string`.
You're checking more than that: You're checking if obj is a `MyOwnGenericClass< string >`.
Nobody said it will always be a `MyOwnGenericClass< something >` and our only headache is to find what that something is.

You can send bools, strings, ints, primitive arrays of int, even a `StringBuilder`.
And then there's your entourage: you could send `MyOwnGenericClass< int >`, `MyOwnGenericClass< string >` (and this is the only one you accept).

Answer (score 1):

```
var test = new MyGenericType<string>();

var genericTypes = test.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
if (genericTypes.Length == 1 && genericTypes[0] == typeof(string))
{
    // Do deserialization
}
else
{
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Type.GetGenericArguments()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericarguments.aspx) to get the actual values of generic arguments a type was created with at runtime:

```
class MyGeneric<TValue> {}

object stringValue = new MyGeneric<string>();
object intValue = new MyGeneric<int>();

// prints True
Console.WriteLine(stringValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(string));
// prints False
Console.WriteLine(intValue.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0] == typeof(string));
```